# Symfony2 Bundle configuration

Tags: symfony

I am trying to use a custom configuration for my bundle

```
#app/config.yml
config.yml
        my_app:
                level1:
                    level2:
                        - "first data"
                        - "second data"
```

How can I get those information a  controller or a service

```
#My/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_app');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('level1')
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayNode('level2')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
    ;
```

This code generate the following error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 317: Unrecognized options "0, 1" under "my_app.level1.level2"
```

How can do that please ?

Comment: You can inject config to your service or set as parameters in `YourBundleExtension.php` file. Search other bundles files and you'll be know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like :

```
->children()
    ->arrayNode('level2')
        ->prototype('scalar')->end()
    ->end()
```

If you need more helps, check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-nodes) for more information